# How to create a Json representation of the diff between 2 complex objects?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

What's are some ways in Kotlin to compare two objects that have many child objects and update a REST backend with just the properties that have changed?

Basically, we have a class that has many child classes (which have their own child classes, and so on), and need to call a REST endpoint and send Json to patch only the properties that have changed.

In our project we're using Retrofit with Gson.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the following object tree (pseudocode):

```
A {
B {
    C {
        a: 15
        b: 12
    },
    c: 4
},
d: 12
```

}

Now some changes could've happened and you need to check it. Your new JSON file might look like this:

```
A {
B {
    C {
        a: 3
        b: 12
    },
    c: 4
},
d: 12
```

}

I would recommend to create the objects and let them check for changes by itself because they know the best if there were any changes and which attributes they have:

```
A:
Changes changes(oldA) {
    Changes changes = b.changes(oldA.b)
    changes.add(Changes(d, oldA.d))
    return changes
```

}

This means you would have a class Changes that behaves like a list and offers the update in form of JSON and every object that is part of the JSON puts its values inside of it.

The only thing that is left for you, is to think about the appropriate JSON format for this list.